# object of class illuminate database eloquent collection could not be converted to int

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am accessing the user table attribute 'role' and want to check if role is 2 then show dashboard but getting this error.
here is my code

```
protected $casts = [
    'role' => 'integer',
];
```

here is my controller function where I am accessing the user role column value. it returns the value in array but I want to compare it with an integer value '2'.

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    $posts = Post::all();
    $email = $request['email'];
    $user = User::where("email",$email)->get(['role']);
    if(Auth:: attempt(['email' => $request['email'] , 'password' => $request['password']]))
    {
        if ($user == 2) {
            return view('admin.dashboard');

        }
        else {
            return view('frontend.layouts.user_login_layout', compact('posts'));
        }
    }else{
        return "wrong User";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem**

```
$user = User::where("email",$email)->get(['role']); // <= look here (fetching)

if ($user == 2) { // <= look here (validation)
  return view('admin.dashboard');
}
```

**Solutions**

***Fetching object***

```
// RETURN me FIRST user FROM collection of users WHERE row email EQUALS $email
$user = User::where("email",$email)->first(); 
// Better aproach is to fail ( throw exseption ) if collection is empty
$user = User::where("email",$email)->firstOrFail();
```

*Note: A collection is an object containing other objects*

If email is a unique value, you can use `->first()` to retrieve the first model matching the query constraints - [source: laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

If you expect multiple records, you can use methods like `->all()` and `->get()` which will retrieve multiple results - [source: laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-models)

***Validation***

At this point, `$user` variable, contains an eloquent object and it's impossible to compare an object with an integer ( `int` ).

What you really want to do: check if the user's role is equaled to 2

```
if ($user->role == 2) { // <= look here 
   return view('admin.dashboard');
}
```

Comment: I have already try this. it shows an exception . property [role] does not exists on this collection instance.

Comment: And when I use if ($user['role'] == 2) it shows undefined index:role

Comment: you should use the same name as the role 'column name' in your database. if you can't find please provide the db schema for your user object.
Like i sad before: $user is an object  not an array !... you cannot access it like an array.

Comment: Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('role');
            $table->timestamp('last_login')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: my column name is role. same as I am using in controller function

Comment: ow i read your error a bit to fast. "property [role] does not exists on this collection instance"
As you can see you have a collection in your $user variable (collection = multiple objects) Do you have multiple records with the same email in your db ??
Try to use ->first() like so:  $user = User::where("email",$email)->first(); This will limit the result to 1 object

Comment: yes ! when I use first it solves my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line in your code

```
$user = User::where("email",$email)->get(['role']);
```

to this

```
$user = User::where("email",$email)->first();
```

as get would return a collection, and then you could check for the user role as

```
if ($user->role == 2) {
```